# How can I draw a head of an arrow at the end of a straight line in Canvas in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-canvas

I am able to draw a straight line in flutter using two offset points. I use the following one to achieve this:

```
canvas.drawLine(lines[i].path[j], lines[i].path[j + 1], paint);
```

I am struggling to find a way to draw a little arrow head at the end of this line. I need some help with the math here please. My mind is sure it can be done

Comment: no need for a complex math - instead first rotate your `Canvas` then call `Canvas.drawPath`

Comment: Can you include your paint class and an image that you're trying to archive?